# Use \verb inside \seqsplit

Tags: verbatim, code, strings

I need to use the `\verb` command inside the `\seqsplit` command. The compiler warns me when I insert `\verb` inside `\seqsplit`. How can I do?

thank you all

EDIT:

```
\seqsplit{\verb |#####|}
```

Error:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please provide a code snippets (such the ones in [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))? Is your problem only a warning? Can you post also the log file of the compilation?

Comment: Don't use \verb inside the argument of other commands.

Comment: The `\verb` command can never be used in the argument to another command. Why not using `\seqsplit{\#\#\#\#\#}`?

Comment: You can use the `cprotect` package and then do `\cprotect\seqsplit{\verb |#####|}`.